# Java Object-Array copy with 1 less

Tags: java, copy

```
public void arrayUpdate(int counter,int counter2){
    int counterShipMemory=0;
    this.playerMemory2= new Player[this.playerMemory.length];
    for(int i = 0; i< this.playerMemory.length;i++){
    this.playerMemory2[i] = this.playerMemory[i];
    }
    this.playerMemory2[counter].shipMemory= new Ship[this.playerMemory2[counter].shipMemory.length-1];
    for(int counter3=0;counter3 <this.playerMemory[counter].shipMemory.length;counter3++){
        if(counter3!=counter2){
            this.playerMemory2[counter].shipMemory[counterShipMemory]=this.playerMemory[counter].shipMemory[counter3];
            counterShipMemory++;
        }
    }
    this.playerMemory[counter].shipMemory = new Ship[playerMemory2[counter].shipMemory.length];
    for(int counter3=0;counter3 <playerMemory2[counter].shipMemory.length;counter3++){
        this.playerMemory[counter].shipMemory[counter3]=playerMemory2[counter].shipMemory[counter3];
    }
```

Explain: 
`counter` is array id from one player.

`counter2` is the array id from a ship that should remove.

The Problem is at line 7(`this.playerMemory2[counter].shipMemory= new Ship`).

If i start this line the `shipMemory` at `playerMemory2` and `playerMemory` change. But why? And how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They change both because they are the same object:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.playerMemory.length; i++){
    this.playerMemory2[i] = this.playerMemory[i];
}
```

with this loop, the two arrays reference the same objects (`playerMemory[i] == playerMemory2[i]`, objects at the same memory adress). Therefore, if you change the `shipMemory`of `playerMemory2[i]`, you also change the `shipMemory` of `playerMemory[i]`.

To prevent this, you can clone each object. Provided you implement a `clone()` method, it would be an easy fix:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.playerMemory.length; i++){
    this.playerMemory2[i] = this.playerMemory[i].clone();
}
```

Now, only the `shipMemory` of `playerMemory2[i]` would change.